# Pass a string parameter to command text with quotes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a parameter to the query but with quotes as a string value.
But I can seem to get it working.
What am I doing wrong here.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SERP_FT_connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT sp.* "
                                         + " FROM [serp_post] sp "
                                         + " LEFT JOIN [serp_m3_data] m3 ON m3.serp_post_id = sp.serp_post_id "
                                         + " WHERE sp.[serp_status_id]='CLEAR_DONE' AND sp.m3UpdateStatus <> '2' AND sp.process_type='POST' AND m3.EGTRCD = '40' AND m3.EPPYME = @paymentTerm ", conn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@paymentTerm";
        param.Value = paymentTerm; // when debugged here it shows as "CH1"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Query looks like this when debugged,

```
SELECT sp.*  FROM [serp_post] sp  LEFT JOIN [serp_m3_data] m3 ON m3.serp_post_id = sp.serp_post_id  WHERE sp.[serp_status_id]='CLEAR_DONE' AND sp.m3UpdateStatus <> '2' AND sp.process_type='POST' AND m3.EGTRCD = '40' AND m3.EPPYME = @paymentTerm
```

Finally the query should look like this value passed with quotes

```
SELECT sp.*  FROM [serp_post] sp  LEFT JOIN [serp_m3_data] m3 ON m3.serp_post_id = sp.serp_post_id  WHERE sp.[serp_status_id]='CLEAR_DONE' AND sp.m3UpdateStatus <> '2' AND sp.process_type='POST' AND m3.EGTRCD = '40' AND m3.EPPYME = 'CH1'
```

Comment: SQL parameters aren't just inserted into the query like that - they're passed *as parameters* to the database. Regardless of what it looks like when debugging, what happens when you execute the query? That looks basically correct to me...

Comment: The code is behaving properly.   The only way to get it to behave the way you are expecting would be to use string replacement in your query, instead of parameters.

Comment: Yeah. It would also be wise to familiarise yourself with your DB's Profiler tool. You'll thank us once you start getting a bit more advanced and use an ORM framework where things become even less transparent.

Comment: @TabAlleman thank you I replaced it in the query instead of parsing it as parameter and It's working.

Comment: @NPras yes thank you for the suggestion I did start using profiler tool and lot easier to debug sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try catch the parameterized query in the Profiler. Correct query will look something like

```
exec sp_executesql N' SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON;SELECT sp.*  FROM [serp_post] sp  LEFT JOIN [serp_m3_data] m3 ON m3.serp_post_id = sp.serp_post_id  WHERE sp.[serp_status_id]='CLEAR_DONE' AND sp.m3UpdateStatus <> '2' AND sp.process_type='POST' AND m3.EGTRCD = '40' AND m3.EPPYME = @paymentTerm',N'@paymentTerm varchar(10)',@paymentTerm='CH1'
```

As Jon Skeet said, SQL parameters aren't inserted into the query.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comments that actually present the PARAMETERS are automatically handled during the post and not LITERAL in the query as to prevent sql-injection.

As for the other answer about double-quotes, I have gotten into the habit of writing my sql in C# as sample below to help prevent accidental double-quotes in-use.

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "", conn);
  cmd.CommandText = 
@"SELECT 
      sp.*
   FROM 
      [serp_post] sp 
         LEFT JOIN [serp_m3_data] m3 
            ON m3.serp_post_id = sp.serp_post_id
   WHERE 
          sp.[serp_status_id]='CLEAR_DONE' 
      AND sp.m3UpdateStatus <> '2' 
      AND sp.process_type='POST' 
      AND m3.EGTRCD = '40' 
      AND m3.EPPYME = @paymentTerm ";
```

Notice the fully readable query without scrolling or forgetting a close double-quote + on next line, etc...  Again, just a style thing on building sql commands.  The leading @ means the entire text until it's closing other double-quote.  Since SQL ignores enter keys in statements, they still work without issue and promote better readability.